# BigContentView does not seem to be updated

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

I am currently working on an android app. I need to notify a user that they have arrived at a place in the normal notification and when the notification is expanded it shows extra info. The usual :)

I am using 2 different remoteViews, one to set the contentView and one to set the bigContentView.

```
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // build notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                    .setColor(Color.CYAN)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                    .setContentText("Content Text");

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.remoteview_notification);
    rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.remoteview_notification_icon, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.remoteview_notification_headline, "Headline");
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.remoteview_notification_short_message, notificationContent.getHeading());
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        notification.contentView = rv; //Alternative to .setContent(rv);
    }
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    RemoteViews rvBig = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.remoteview_big_notification);
    rvBig.setImageViewResource(R.id.remoteview_big_notification_icon, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    rvBig.setTextViewText(R.id.remoteview_big_notification_headline, notificationContent.getHeading());
    rvBig.setTextViewText(R.id.remoteview_big_notification_full_message, notificationContent.getBodyText());
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        notification.bigContentView = rvBig;
    }
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

The problem is my expanded notification does not show up when I drag down? Any help will be appreciated. It feels like it  is just something small that is not yet set/ set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that my intentId might not be unique throughout my app. I have seen people use the current system  to ensure uniqueness.

```
NOTIFICATION_ID = system.currenttimemillis();

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```